# I want to use keras layers within my custom layer, but I am unable to return the output of the layer as a tensor instead of an object

Tags: tensorflow, keras, type-conversion, keras-layer, tf.keras

> The error shown is 
>   Failed to convert object of type class 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D' 
>   to Tensor.
>   I have tried many things but I am unable to sort this error.

````
```class Mixed_pooling():
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(Mixed_pooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

      def build(self, input_shape):
          self.alpha = self.add_weight(
          name='alpha', shape=(1,),
          initializer='random_normal',
          trainable=True
          )
          super(Mixed_pooling, self).build(input_shape)

      def call(self, x):
          x1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='VALID')
          x2 = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='VALID')
          outputs = tf.add(tf.multiply(x1, self.alpha), tf.multiply(x2, (1-self.alpha)))
          return outputs```
````

Comment: Layer itself is a class object, just like your `Mixed_pooling()`. You need to instantiate those objects in your `build()`, e.g. `self.maxpool=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()`, `self.avgpool =  tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D()`, and then use them on tensor during call: `x1 = self.maxpool(x1)`, `x2 = self.avgpool(x2)`

Comment: You are not giving any inputs to the internal layers, you should be using x for this, right?

Comment: @Slowpoke Thank you so much for your help. I applied your idea, and then had to change all imports to ```tensorflow.keras``` instead of directly importing from keras, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comment Section (Thanks to [Slowpoke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1692060/slowpoke)), for the benefit of the community.

As `tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D()` and `tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D()` are class objects, you need to instantiate the objects in `build` function and later use them in `call` function.

**Modified Code -**

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Mixed_pooling():
      def __init__(self, **kwargs):
          super(Mixed_pooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

      def build(self, input_shape):
          self.alpha = self.add_weight(
          name='alpha', shape=(1,),
          initializer='random_normal',
          trainable=True
          )
          self.maxpool=tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='VALID')
          self.avgpool =  tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='VALID')
          super(Mixed_pooling, self).build(input_shape)

      def call(self, x):
          x1 = self.maxpool(x)
          x2 = self.avgpool(x)
          outputs = tf.add(tf.multiply(x1, self.alpha), tf.multiply(x2, (1-self.alpha)))
          return outputs

layer1 = Mixed_pooling()
print(layer1)
```

**Output -**

```
<__main__.Mixed_pooling object at 0x7fce31e46550>
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Slowpoke - Feel free to modify the answer if you would like to improve it. Thanks